# What is Oscar Wilde's "Blue China"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

"I find it harder and harder every day to live up to my blue china."
What did Oscar Wilde mean by Blue China?? Did he use it to refer to his friends who betrayed him??if yes,why "blue china"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it deals with history rather than language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an aesthete, Wilde decorated his rooms at Magdalen College with many *objets d'art*, including blue [china](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/china) (porcelain).

The famous *"I find it harder and harder every day to live up to my blue china"* I think refers to the **perfect beauty and unsurpassable aesthetics of the china that we as humans could never hope to attain**.

Wilde is saying that an **object of beauty** ("blue china") **can be something to measure one's life against.**

There's some information about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Wilde#Magdalen_College.2C_Oxford).

[Blue china](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=blue+china&biw=1574&bih=812&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI1aCXtejkyAIVgewUCh0wIQlh#tbm=isch&q=19th+century+blue+china&imgrc=HJjZRViWeYDlyM%3A) can indeed look amazing:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP doesn't know what 'China' is so I'll add that it's porcelain

Comment: +1 but I think this image is maybe  more illustrative https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=blue+china&biw=1574&bih=812&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI1aCXtejkyAIVgewUCh0wIQlh#tbm=isch&q=19th+century+blue+china&imgrc=HJjZRViWeYDlyM%3A

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed. Updated the link.

Comment: A similar interpretation might also be that he finds it difficult to be the type of person that deserves objects of beauty or that can live the kind of life a blue china object suggests, not so much that we as individuals match the beauty of the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's also a class issue. In the 18th century, an object (like blue china) acquired its status through ownership. Chinese porcelains were prized by the aristocracy; the best Chinese porcelains were made for the Emperor. But in the 19th century this status is reversed when the object is owned by the nouveau-riches. Now the object confers its high status on the owner. Hence, the desire to 'live up' to one's Blue China.